# Cannot update to Safari 11

Tags: safari, mac-appstore, software-update

I'm running El Captain 10.11.6. I've recently tried to update to Safari 11 using App Store as I had done in several other machines with the same setup. Safari 11 downloaded fine but something went wrong during reboot and I ended up reinstalling El Captain 10.11.6. Now I'm back to Safari 9 but App Store thinks that I've already installed Safari 11 and so no longer offers Safari 11 as an update.

I assume that this will fix itself *if and when* a new release of Safari 11 comes out.

Can I fix this otherwise in the meantime?

Comment: Safari is part of the update packages/process of macOS as a whole.  Did you apply all of the updates?

Comment: @Allan, yes, I did, but something went wrong and the system was weird after reboot. So I reinstalled El Captain 10.11.6.

Comment: @Allan, reinstalled on top of what was there.

Comment: What do you get if you issue the command:  `cat /Library/Receipts/InstallHistory.plist | grep -i safari`

Comment: @Allan, there is only one El Capitan line: `<string>com.apple.pkg.Safari10.0.1ElCapitan</string>`.

Comment: According to that, Safari 11 is *not* installed so the updates should install it.  Just for verification, go to this site:  http://whatsmyuseragent.com/ and verify the version of Safari your running.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Today I installed Security Upgrade 2018-001 and then App Store offered Safari 11.0.3, which I installed with no problems. This solution is mentioned [here](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/8269115).