# Update Safari on High Sierra

Tags: macos, safari, high-sierra, software-update

Somehow Safari got reverted to v11.1.2 on my High Sierra box. I know I had 13.1.2 before. But App Store thinks I already updated so I can't click "update to 13.1.2".

Is version **11.1.2** at least at security parity with 13.1.2? I'd rather update?

Comment: See https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204416

Comment: See also https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/305583/cannot-update-to-safari-11

Answer (score 2):

Each version of Safari is more secure than earlier versions. I would suggest you upgrade to at least version 13.1.2. You should be able to upgrade Safari by going to the AppStore. Go to the app store and see if you can download a newer version of Safari.

[This link](https://www.whatismybrowser.com/guides/how-to-update-your-browser/safari) will take you to a page where it talks about upgrading Safari.